# What is the difference between the adjectives novel and new?

Tags: differences, synonyms

The coronavirus is "novel", which made this adjective more common. I interpret it as a synonym of new, but is there any difference between the two?

[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/novel), for instance, does not make a great distinction:

> **novel** 2  [adj]:
>
> Strikingly new, unusual, or different.

Comment: Well, you normally wouldn't say "I'd rather own a novel car than a used one".

Comment: In my field of software development, I've been encouraged not to rename module_x as new_module_x. The reason? At some point, new_module_x will be old, and the adjective confusing. Can you imagine if (God forbid) Covid-19 were still around in 2030? It wouldn't be *new* by then. But might still be a *novel* form of a respiratory syndrome.

Comment: "Strikingly new", is a good description IMO.

Comment: Novel is generally a stronger term, implying something more than just a different age or purchase date. If you bought a new car that was exactly the same model as the old one, it would be "new" but not "novel": novel implies a clear difference.

Comment: **Novel** - an item that new and has not been seen before. In the language of patent applications, an item must be "novel", i.e. not based upon a previous item. It must have something unique about it.   **New**, may refer to a newer item or version, or type - i.e. a variant on an older or common version of a known object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as Weather Vane says, '**novel virus**' forces such a specifying definition on 'novel' that it is perhaps better regarded here as part of a fixed expression.

Indeed, [CALD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/novel) does list this usage but adds caveats:

> **novel** [medical ... specialized]
>
> used to refer to a new strain (= type) of a virus that has not been
> seen before:
>
> - *The COVID-19 pathogen is a novel coronavirus*.
> - *A novel virus in swine is closely related to the human hepatitis E virus.* [6 Oct 2020; Proc NAS]

However, 'novel' in this sense has been around since at least the 1970s, when the terms 'novel proteins' and 'novel compounds' were often met in scientific papers. Perhaps 'new to science' is a good synonym.

In general usage, the difference between these two fairly close synonyms is brought out by this statement from [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/novel#:%7E:text=If%20something%20is%20so%20new,of%20before%2C%20call%20it%20novel.&text=Whereas%20new%20is%20a%20Germanic,also%20original%2C%20fresh%20and%20unique.):

> ***novel** If something is so new and original that it's never been seen, used or even thought of before, call it novel.*

There is an emphasis on originality, freshness, a new idea being involved. A 'novelty item' is (aimed at being) a surprising, inventive, almost ingenious knickknack.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/novel) at the moment (08 Nov 2020) carries only the generally upbeat sense (doubtless the default sense prior to the 'novel virus' usage):

> **novel** [adjective] ...
>
> New or unusual in an interesting way.
>
> - He hit on a novel idea to solve his financial problems.

Though 'novel virus' and 'novelty item' are terms evoking very different scenarios.

Comment: Interesting and confusing, novel can mean both "never thought before" and "newly discovered, but not necessarily newly brought into existance".

I also found this definition of new in the Merriam-Webster:

"(1): having been seen, used, or known for a short time : NOVEL
rice was a new crop for the area"

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti The distinction works the other way as well, the three millionth washing machine of a given model to leave the factory is certainly _new_ but it is in no way _novel_.

Answer (score 9):

A **novel virus** is not necessarily **new**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novel_virus) says

> A novel virus is a virus that has not previously been recorded. It can be a virus that is isolated from its natural reservoir or isolated as the result of spread to an animal or human host where the virus had not been identified before. It can be an emergent virus, one that represents a new virus, but it can also be an extant virus that has not been previously identified.

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novel) says

> **novel**
>
> **1 b** not previously identified
> *transmission of a novel coronavirus, a novel genetic mutation*

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a new car**

[image]

**Here is a novel car**

[image]

Comment: One picture .... (although Top Gear have, I think,  pre-empted this design).

Answer (score 2):

Also worth mentioning that "novel" is a jargon term of patent law with a particular legal weight. Many claims of "novel" are made in scientific papers with an eye to patent law. Which has meant that "novel" has become the common term in science for a never-seen-before discovery or invention, as opposed to the use of a different adjective with a similar meaning, such as "new".

Comment: Very true, +1. It is very common in scientific literature to read papers bringing up unprecedented work like new discoveries and solutions, and these will be rightfully tagged as novel.

Answer (score 2):

In French, such a difference between "nouveau / nouvelle" (novel ?) and "neuf / neuve" (new) may exist.

As to follow the washing machine example given by @BoldBen:
"the three millionth [one] of a given model to leave the factory is certainly new", hence translates as "une machine [à laver] neuve" (as opposed to second-hand) and not "une nouvelle machine". I checked the etymology of "novel", and indeed it comes from French, so it may be a clue.

Comment: Is there any etymological relation between neuf (9) and neuf (new)?

Comment: I could not find any, but I'd gladly let somebody more knowledgeable answer this.

Answer (score -1):

"There are many like it but this one is mine"

What is new (my new rifle) is not necessarily novel. There are many like it.

Comment: Why the downvote?